# How to update Column name at the time of exporting CSV using Jmeter beanshell post processor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, post-processor

I had exported the response in CSV using JMeter beanshell post processor using following code but column name is not present.

```
f = new FileOutputStream("CaseCreate.csv", true); 

p = new PrintStream(f);

p.println("TicketID" + "\t" +("${TID}") + '|' + ("${vendorTicket}")+'|' +("${__Random(0,5,priority)}")+ '|' + ("${RTime}") + '|' + ("${OnsiteTime}"));
```

How column name can be updated at the time of exporting the csv?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is your code and asking us why it doesn't add header is weird, just add the appropriate logic to write the necessary header line to the file.

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) for scripting so consider migrating on next available opportunity.

Also avoid referring JMeter variables as `${TID}`, you should use `vars.get("TID")` construction instead where `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dmitri